# is loaded model does not need eval?

Tags: pytorch

tryint to use the test after I load the model

```
net = net.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
net.eval()
```

but this spit the error

> ```
> net.eval() AttributeError: '_IncompatibleKeys' object has no attribute 'eval'
> ```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

here you don't need to assign `net.load_state_dict` to `net`

```py
net = net.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
```

just used

```py
net.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
net.eval()
```

more see [Recommended approach for saving a model](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/notes/serialization.html#recommended-approach-for-saving-a-model)